# How to bind SelectedValue of DropdownList to DataSoruce when drop down is populated programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a GridView. When I go into edit mode on a row, I want one of the columns to be a dropdown. My first draft included this:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("type_name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ctlItemType" runat="server" datasourceid="dsItemTypes"
                  DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" 
                  selectedvalue='<%# Bind("item_type_id") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I should clarify that my data source included "type_name" as the name of the type and "item_type_id" as the ID corresponding to that name. That worked great. Cool.

But I need to restrict the values appearing in the drop down depending on other data about the record. So okay, fine, I removed the datasourceid, and instead populated the dropdown with code:

```
Private Sub ItemsGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) 
    Handles ItemsGridView.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
        Dim ctlItemType As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ctlItemType")

        Dim parent_id = ItemsGridView.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values(1)
        ctlItemType.DataSource = ItemTypeActions.List(parent_id)
        ctlItemType.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

That blows up with a "SelectedValue not found" error, I presume because it's trying to set the selected value before I populate the values.

So I tried setting the SelectedValue in code also. After the DataBind above I added:

```
            ctlItemType.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "item_type_id")
```

That displays fine when I go into edit mode, but when I click "Update", it blows up, because item_type_id doesn't get included in the list of parameters passed to the update function. Because it's not Bind'ed, it's just set with an Eval.

So how do I make this work? Is there a way to bind a control to a datasource with code? I could find anything like DataBinder.Eval that is equivalent to <%# bind("whatever") %>. Or ... what?

Comment: In the code block where you populate the DDL in the EditTemplate, check if the `item_type_id` that is coming from the GridView is present in the DDL and if so set the SelectedValue also programatically instead of inline.

Comment: @VDWWD If I'm understanding you correctly, I did that. See my "selectedvalue=" statement above. Yes, that sets the value so the dropdown displays correctly. But it doesn't bind the value to the datasource, so when the user clicks "Update", it doesn't save the new value.

Comment: What does your update event look like?